# I want to find the number of carry operation in multi digit number problem

Tags: c

I'm not getting the correct number of carry operation through my code

this code is finding carry operation from right to left,whenever it finds a carry operation it returns ( found),,,let two integers a=362175600 b=1479992559  there are 5 carries in second,third fourth, seventh and ninth position,,,therefore,the output should be:-1 found,, 2 found 3 found,, not found ,,not found,, 4 found,, not found,, 5 found ,,not found

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
        int a,b,count,max,min,j,rem_max,rem_min;

        while((scanf("%d%d",&a,&b))==2){

            if(a==0 && b==0){
                break;
            }
            else{
                if(a > b){
                    max=a;
                    min=b;
                }
                else if(b > a){
                    min=a;
                    max=b;
                }
                else{
                    max=a;
                    min=b;
                }


                count=0;
                j=1;

                while(max!=0){
                    rem_max=max%10;
                    rem_min=min%10;

                    if((rem_max+rem_min)>9){
                        count++;

                        printf("%d found\n",j);
                        max=(max/10)+1;
                        min=min/10;
                        j++;
                    }
                    else if((rem_max+rem_min)<9){

                        max=max/10;
                        min=min/10;

                        printf("not found\n");
                    }
                    else{
                        max=max/10;
                        min=min/10;

                    }

                }
                printf("-----------------------\n");
                printf("%d\n",count);

            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

In the following example the output should be  5 but  I've got 3 through my code,
My output from this code is:- `1 found,, 2 found,, not found,, not found,, not found,, 3 found,, not found,, 4 found,, not found,so,it shows the number of carry operation is  4. But it should be:- 1 found,,2 found,, 3 found,, not found,, not found,,4 found,, not found,, 5 found,, not found,so the actual number of carry operation is  5`

Comment: You read and compare non-initialised variables. E.g. here `while(a!=0 && b!=0)`.

Comment: You ignore the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Please explain in detail what your program is supposed to do. Give input examples with desired output and current output.

Comment: All comments still stand. Especially the first one.

Comment: let,a=922243926 b=1449529480
my output for this is:-
1 found
2 found
not found
not found
not found
3 found
not found
4 found
not found
-----------------------
4
But it should be:-         
1 found
2 found
3  found
not found
not found
4 found
not found
5 found
not found
-----------------------
5

Comment: @SunjareeIbnZulfiker for clarifications please [edit] the question. Also read this: [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: thanks a lot dude!!!!!!

Comment: "But it should be". Why?

Comment: okay I will try my best from next @Jabberwocky

Comment: this code is finding carry operation from right to left,whenever it finds a carry operation it returns ( found),,,In my following example  there are 5 carries in  second,third fourth, seventh and ninth position,,,therefore,the output should be:-1 found,, 2 found 3 found,, not found ,,not found,, 4 found,, not found,, 5 found ,,not found @Yunnosch

Comment: Did you notice the comment by Jabberwocky? Please [edit] your question to add information, instead of hiding them in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With inputs of a=362175600 b=1479992559, the statement `max=(max/10)+1;` causes 14799 to become 14800 and produces bad result.
Using a separate `carry` variable will correct the problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    int a = 1,b = 1,count,max,min,j,rem_max,rem_min;
    int carry = 0;

    while ( a != 0 && b != 0) {
        scanf ( "%d%d", &a, &b);
        max = b;
        min = a;
        if ( a > b) {
            max = a;
            min = b;
        }

        count = 0;
        j = 0;

        while ( max != 0) {
            rem_max = max % 10;
            rem_min = min % 10;
            max /= 10;
            min /= 10;

            if ( ( rem_max + rem_min + carry) > 9) {//also add carry
                count++;
                carry = 1;//set carry
                printf("%d found\n",j);
                j++;
            }
            else {
                carry = 0;//un set carry
                printf ( "not found\n");
            }
        }
        printf ( "-----------------------\n");
        printf ( "%d\n", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```